# How to test Azure createUiDefinition.json?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to get my product listed in azure marketplace. I have written the following template file(s):

1. createUiDefinition.json
2. mainTemplate.json
3. parameters.json``

I am able to test mainTemplate.json along with parameters.json using azure-cli with following command:

`az group deployment validate --resource-group rgupta --template-file mainTemplate.json --parameters @parameters.json`

I am also able to test createUiDefinition.json using "Portal UI editor" in old.armviz.io.

I had to use VS code to debug some of the issues found in createUiDefinition.json.

However I don't find a way to test this end to end. I would like to simulate a behaviour that is same as when this solution goes to market place.

Is there any Microsoft recommended way to test this.

Comment: This createUiDefinition.json is specifically for creating a template for use in the azure portal. I doubt this is what you want. But your question is quite lacking in details so it is hard to help you. Go read up on arm templates, how to use and deploy: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/

The readme on that page has many links and useful info for you.

Comment: Maybe this question is tagged incorrectly, but I don't think it should be so badly downvoted: There simply **isn't** a good workflow to do end-to-end tests of the UI definition.

You can test the ARM template or the UI definition on its own, but there is no way to test the pass-through of parameters from one to the other

Answer (score 2):

One of the option seem to be mentioned here:
https://github.com/tomconte/base-solution-template

Would like to know if there is some other option using visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this URL http://old.armviz.io/#/ . This will help you to validate your CreateUIdefinition.json, just go to portal UI editor button on left side, copy your createUIdefinitions.json code and hit on the preview to unit test your UI on the Azure portal. It also validates your UI definition.

Apart from this The URL also has a lot of options that we have developing AWS Cloudformation templates ( drag and drop resources, auto-generate template)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Create UI Definition Sandbox](https://portal.azure.com/?feature.customPortal=false&#blade/Microsoft_Azure_CreateUIDef/SandboxBlade) as described here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/test-createuidefinition

Comment: It is much better to give some more detailed explanation.